# SoundCloud API: Tweeting on upload and disable comments

Tags: soundcloud

The following PHP code uploads a new track to SoundCloud successfully, but the tweet is not sent.

Is there something I need to have in there as well in order to do this?

```
$track = $soundcloud->post('tracks',
        array(
                'track[asset_data]' => '@audio.mp3', 
                'track[title]' => "my audio",
                'track[description]' => "Updated: " . date('l jS F Y h:i:s A'),
                'track[sharing]' => 'public',
                'track[shared_to][connections][][id]' => '123',
                'track[sharing_note]' => 'Have a listen to'
                ));
```

Also I'd like to be able to disable comments on the audio I upload, but I wasn't sure what the parameter for that would be too?

Thanks!

dB

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable the repro the sharing problem. Please note that sometimes sharing on other social networks doesn't happen right away. Are you still having trouble? Here's the code I used:

```
<?php

require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

$client = new Services_Soundcloud("foo", "bar");
$client->setAccessToken('ACCESS_TOKEN');

$track = $client->post('tracks', array(
    'track[title]' => 'Foooo',
    'track[asset_data]' => '@/Users/paul/audio.wav',
    'track[sharing]' => 'public',
    'track[shared_to][connections][][id]' => 'CONNECTION_ID',
    'track[sharing_note]' => 'Check it out'
));

print_r($track);
```

Also verify that your CONNECTION_ID is correct. Some code to get a list of connections so you can verify the id:

```
<?php

require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

$client = new Services_Soundcloud("foo", "bar");
$client->setAccessToken('ACCESS_TOKEN');

print_r(json_decode($client->get('me/connections')));
```

Unfortunately there's no way currently to disable comments via the API. I'll file a bug and see about getting this fixed.

Hope that helps!