# Programmatically setting quiet mode options (comments/stats) through SoundCloud's API

Tags: soundcloud

I'm in the process of migrating my company's audio from the old hosting provider to SoundCloud. I've written a script to automate this process which uploads the audio file, its thumbnail, and writes all the relevant metadata as well.

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to set the quiet mode options, like disabling comments or hiding the stats, programmatically.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124423/soundcloud-api-tweeting-on-upload-and-disable-comments) from April 2012, which mentions that the API doesn't support it. I was wondering if it had since been updated? And if so, what are the fields that need to be specified? eg. similar to track[title] or track[asset_data].

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE (3/8/2013)**

The folks from SoundCloud have confirmed that toggling quiet mode options is not currently possible through their API.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, you could have in the old question for which you have shared a link. The interrogator would have arrived at a conclusion. Try commenting there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to comment yet and a separate answer on that thread doesn't seem right either, hence this post.

Comment: The documentation lists a track property called "commentable" but it does not seem to work. "downloadable" is similar and I can toggle it through the API as expected. Any ideas?